# I need to use jsoup selector for more than one p tags

Tags: java, jsoup

Hi i have an html code  suppose,

```html
<P>This is Stack overflow</p>
<p>---------------</p>
<p>---------------</p>
<p>This is stack overflow2</p>
```

In general i have 100 p tags in my html code i need to select first 50 out of them.

I need to select all the `<p>` tags from the `<p>` tag which contain "This is Stack overflow" .  until the `<p>` tag which contain "This is stack overflow2".
is it possible to use jsoup because i am using it from java class.

Thanks In advance

Comment: I am tring this,      bw.write(doc.select("p:contains(Stack)").text());    (where doc is the html )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what exactly you are requesting, but this is a start:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class JsoupTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String html = "<P>This is Stack overflow</p>"
                + "<p>---------------</p>"
                + "<p>---------------</p>"
                + "<p>This is stack overflow2</p>";
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
        Elements elements = doc.select("p");

        for(Element e : elements) {
            System.out.println(e.text());
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can adapt the loop and add conditions, depending on what you want to include.

These links are helpful:

- https://jsoup.org/cookbook/
- http://www.mkyong.com/java/jsoup-html-parser-hello-world-examples/

Comment: If i need to select first three tags and not the last tag then what condition should i adopt ?

Comment: Well it depends :) If you want a certain number of tags to be selected, then I would suggest a counter in the loop. If the selection depends on the content of the tag, you should compare e.text() to a text with .equals(). Be more specific !

Comment: @Saket Sinha you'll want to use pseudo-selectors (:contains) to select the "this is stack overflow" and then use nth-child to grab the elements you need.  There is no need to loop over and perform .equals for what is otherwise a rather simple CSS selector.

Comment: See the pseudo-selectors on jsoup doc: https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax

Comment: @ZackTeater can ypu please post an example to use the pseudo selector as i am not clear with the link .

Comment: @Tim Thanks condition on e.text() did work.

Comment: @SaketSinha: good :)